# Multiplying 2 32 bit ints without integer overflow

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

I would like to multiple 2 positive signed 32-bit integers `i` and `j`. The worst case scenario is when `i` and `j` are both `INT_MAX` where their product is within the limit of a 64-bit integer, but when I perform the operation

```
int i = INT_MAX;
int j = INT_MAX;
long long int res = i * j;
```

I get garbage due to integer overflow. So I've typically solved that problem by casting  `i` or `j` to a `long long int`

```
int i = INT_MAX;
int j = INT_MAX;
long long int res = (long long int)i * j;
```

Is this the typical workaround for this issue? Are there other ways that may be better?

Comment: Tangent: Prefer `static_cast<long long>(i)` over a C-style cast.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is correct, and standard enough that quality compilers will recognize it. Some CPU's have dedicated 32x32->64 multiplication instructions, and you can reasonably expect a compiler to use such an instruction despite the cast.